# Loading python packages takes excessively long (3.5 on Anaconda for Windows)

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have some performance issues in my development environment that I can't seem to resolve. The most blatant issue is the fact that loading packages takes several orders of magnitude longer than it should:

[image]

This has started happening randomly at some point recently in the development process. I suspect that it has something to do with package updates. The reason is that I have tried to recreate the environment with a requirements.txt with fixed versions on 3 different machines with different versions of Anaconda, and the problem occurs on all three machines, and it didn't occur on any of the machines with older versions of my code.

I am worried about pushing any recent commits to production because this might destroy the performance in unforeseen ways. Aside from the long imports there are random unpredictable kernel crashes happening in some of my own functions that are seemingly impossible to debug (when running step-by-step with pdb they run without issue).

Is there any tool to debug something like this? Could it be a conda- or Windows-related issue? I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: Is this always on Jupyter? or same issue from vanilla interpreter? E.g., how does `python -m timeit ‘import pandas’` from the activated environment behave?

Comment: `24.4 sec per loop` for `python -m timeit -n 1 -r 1 "import pandas"` - so even worse (maybe jupyter preloads some of pandas' dependencies).

Comment: What does `python -c ‘import sys; print(sys.path)’` look like? (consider adding to question). Is it looking for/loading packages from unexpected places, e.g., somewhere other than the environment? Sharing the `requirements.txt` might also be helpful (if possible).

Comment: The path is too long to paste here, but it starts like this: `['', 'C:\\Users\\[username]\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\py35\\python35.zip'...`, and everything after that points to the same `\py35` directory. [Link to requirements.txt](https://pastebin.com/zTamknXZ).

Comment: What exact commands are used to create the `requirements.txt` and to recreate the environment?

Comment: `requirements.txt` is created manually, since the development environment contains some clunk that is not needed in production (e.g. jupyter). The environment is created with `conda create -n "py35" python=3.5` and then `pip install -r "requirements.txt"`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's directly related, but why use pip to manage the packages?

Comment: My sysadmin uses pip for deployment. What would be your recommendation?